# missing the required build settings for Android, Steroids Appgyver

Tags: cordova, steroids

I have an application witch I build it multiple times for android before Steroids changed Android build types to Crosswalk/ARM/WebView.
Now i get an error for the same application:

> Build for Android with Platform WebView could not be started. Your
>   application is missing the required build settings. Configure them at
>   ‘Configure Build Settings’.

keystore, keystore alias, Package Identifier is set like in the [build config manual](https://academy.appgyver.com/categories/8-distribution/contents/53-android-build-configuration) and min-SDK 14 and Max-SDK 19 is what I've set already.
What should I fix in config?

Comment: did you ever find this?

Comment: @whizzzkid tragically no. I usually create the app for ios then I migrate to phonegap for android build

Comment: Cool, anyways if you still are willing to add crosswalk to your project. Use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-android-crosswalk Works great for me